# Is there a good non-dialog timepiacker library?

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm looking for a way to implement a timepicker inside my app. For UX reasons I souldn't use any dialogs, therefore I need to place this directly inside fragment.

I tried to butcher the standard timepicker (the noncircular one), however the results were poor.

I'm looking for something like there is inside Samsung clock app:
http://www.samsunggalaxys4.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/samsung-galaxy-s4-snooze-sluimeren-instellen.jpg

Just up and down button, few digits. Simple.

Yes - I could just write the code for my own, however from my expereience, there is a lot of fine tuning inside all viewable components to make them look and behave user friendly. To be honest - I'm not very good at this sort of thing.

So - do you know any source that could help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial (
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_timepicker_control.htm), i think it can help you:

Activity:

```
package com.example.timepicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private TimePicker timePicker1;
   private TextView time;
   private Calendar calendar;
   private String format = "";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
      time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      showTime(hour, min);
   }

   public void setTime(View view) {
      int hour = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
      int min = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
      showTime(hour, min);
   }

   public void showTime(int hour, int min) {
      if (hour == 0) {
         hour += 12;
         format = "AM";
      } else if (hour == 12) {
         format = "PM";
      } else if (hour > 12) {
         hour -= 12;
         format = "PM";
      } else {
         format = "AM";
      }
      time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(" : ").append(min)
      .append(" ").append(format));
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

XML View:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/time_pick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/set_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:onClick="setTime"
        android:text="@string/time_save" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/set_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/set_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:text="@string/time_current"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/time_selected"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Strings helpers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">TimePicker</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="time_picker_example">Time Picker Example</string>
    <string name="time_pick">Pick the time and press save button</string>
    <string name="time_save">Save</string>
    <string name="time_selected"></string>
    <string name="time_current">The Time is:</string>
</resources>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Well, as I said - I tried to fiddle with this. Yes, it does the job, but it's dreadful to stylize and in my use - quite unreadable. But hey - it's something, right?

Comment: Please include a few words of explanation as to how this solves the posters problem.